# Shall one use jQuery.getJSON or jQuery.ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there an advantage in using jQueries getJSON instead of jQuery.ajax?

Beside that it is shorter?

But exactly this shortage makes me think if it isn't risky to use getJSON.

If I later find out that I need one of the many options, which jQuery.ajax provides, I have to change a lot in my code.

With using the ajax.method I'm just adding one setting and finished.

So therefore my question:

Is getJSON used only for simplicity- and brevity-reasons? Or are there other advantages which I don't know yet?

Comment: yes, `getJSON` is used for simplicity, and for explicitly saying that you expect a json result, where it already is parsed to objects

Comment: `$.getJSON()` is just shorthand `$.ajax()`function so whats the confusion????

Comment: https://medium.com/@KDweber89/ajax-vs-getjson-ca910fa6854e#.aqpwhhpdg

Comment: @Satpal That's exactly my question. Is it just a shorthand or is there something else what I don't know? If there isn't anything else, then it is answered now because: Yes, it is just a shorthand.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: `$.getJSON()` gets text AND parses it to a json object with `$.parseJSON()`. So it returns a JSON object rather than text.

Comment: You're over-thinking this. But if you're really concerned the source code for all of jQuery is freely available so you can easily see exactly what getJSON() does.